# Ubuntu 18.04 installation failed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive

I have tried to install ubuntu on my HDD, I forgot to disable secure boot. When I boot I'm presented with the grub command line.

[image: Grub command line]

After the installation and I went to my windows which is on SSD and I'm not able to find the HDD drive, where ubuntu was installed.

And I did try to reinstall again, but I got the following error.

> comreset failed (errno= -16)

[image: comreset failed image]

Someone please help me, I'm not able to use my HDD.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! **:-)** so what happens if you disable secure boot and re-install? (as is never worked anyway)???

Comment: If I try reinstall, I would get the errno= -16 error.

Comment: Please reboot with the live USB, choose `Try Ubuntu`, go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and execute `sudo lshw -class disk -class storage`.  Then [edit] your question  and provide the output to that and then leave a comment **@Fabby**

Comment: Even if I choose try Ubuntu, I still get errno= -16 error.

Comment: **Unfortunately** we're seeing this more and more: It looks like your HDD is a Cheap! Crap! Inc! HDD which has specialised drivers under Windows which allows it to be used as a data drive but is unrecognised as a boot device under anything else.  Do you have the hardware manufacturer ID from your Technical documentation???  If still under warranty: get a full refund and buy a good brand.  If not under warranty: buy a good brand USB drive and install Ubuntu on there or on the SSD.  ***Sorry!***

Answer (score 0):

You can create a partition table on your HDD with Gparted and restore it, however you will lose all your data on it. This can be done in the `Try Ubuntu without installing` option of Live Ubuntu (the ISO you wrote onto the USB or CDROM you installed from).

1. Find the Gparted application and launch it.
2. Change the dropdown to the name of your HDD (e.g: /dev/sdb). If unsure, look at the size of the disk.
3. Select the "Device" tab at the top, and then select "Create Partition Table". The type can be whatever you want, but msdos is recommended.
4. You should now see unallocated space on the device in Gparted. Now make a new partition with the filesystem NTFS (NOT EXT4!!!).
5. Confirm your operations, and once complete, your HDD will be in full working state!

Comment: But when I use, try without intsallation. I'm getting comreset failed(errno = -16) error.

Comment: Use Gparted live instead. You can boot into it and use the application without installing anything. https://gparted.org/livecd.php